# Plot of function, DomainError. Exponentiation yielding a complex result requires a complex argument

Tags: plot, jupyter-notebook, julia, newtons-method

**Background**

I read [here](http://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/105/applications/NEWT.HTM) that newton method fails on function `x^(1/3)` when it's inital step is 1. I am tring to test it in julia jupyter notebook.

1. I want to print a plot of function `x^(1/3)`
2. then I want to run code

```
f = x->x^(1/3)
D(f) = x->ForwardDiff.derivative(f, float(x))
x = find_zero((f, D(f)),1, Roots.Newton(),verbose=true)
```

**Problem:**
How to print chart of function `x^(1/3)` in range eg.`(-1,1)`

**I tried**

```
f = x->x^(1/3)
plot(f,-1,1)
```

I got

[image]

I changed code to

```
f = x->(x+0im)^(1/3)
plot(f,-1,1)
```

I got

[image]

I want my plot to look like a plot of `x^(1/3)` in google
[image]

> However I can not print more than a half of it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `x^(1/3)` does not always return a real (as in numbers) result or the real cube root of `x`. For negative numbers, the exponentiation function with some powers like (1/3 or 1.254 and I suppose all non-integers) will return a `Complex`. For type-stability requirements in Julia, this operation applied to a negative `Real` gives a `DomainError`. This behavior is also noted in [Frequently Asked Questions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/index.html#faq-domain-errors-1) section of Julia manual.

```
julia> (-1)^(1/3)
ERROR: DomainError with -1.0:
Exponentiation yielding a complex result requires a complex argument.
Replace x^y with (x+0im)^y, Complex(x)^y, or similar.

julia> Complex(-1)^(1/3)
0.5 + 0.8660254037844386im
```

Note that The behavior of returning a complex number for exponentiation of negative values is not really different than, say, MATLAB's behavior

```
>>> (-1)^(1/3)

ans =

0.5000 + 0.8660i
```

What you want, however, is to plot *the real cube* root.

You can go with

```
plot(x -> x < 0 ? -(-x)^(1//3) : x^(1//3), -1, 1)
```

to enforce real cube root or use the built-in `cbrt` function for that instead.

```
plot(cbrt, -1, 1)
```

It also has an alias `∛`.

```
plot(∛, -1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

That Google plot makes no sense to me. For `x > 0` it's ok, but for negative values of `x` the correct result is complex, and the Google plot appears to be showing the *negative of the absolute value*, which is strange.

Below you can see the output from Matlab, which is less fussy about types than Julia. As you can see it does not agree with your plot.

[image: Plot of x^(1/3)]

From the plot you can see that positive `x` values give a real-valued answer, while negative `x` give a complex-valued answer. The reason Julia errors for negative inputs, is that they are very concerned with type stability. Having the output type of a function depend on the input *value* would cause a type instability, which harms performance. This is less of a concern for Matlab or Python, etc.

If you want a plot similar the above in Julia, you can define your function like this:

```
f = x -> sign(x) * abs(complex(x)^(1/3))
```

**Edit:** Actually, a better and faster version is

```
f = x -> sign(x) * abs(x)^(1/3)
```

Yeah, it looks awkward, but that's because you want a really strange plot, which imho makes no sense for the function `x^(1/3)`.

Answer (score 1):

F(x) is an **odd function**, you just use `[0 1]` as input variable.

The plot on `[-1 0]` is deducted as follow
[image]

## The code is below

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function f 
f = lambda x: x**(1/3)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, num = 100)
x2 = np.linspace(-1, 0, num = 100)
ax.plot(x1, f(x1))
ax.plot(x2, -f(x1[::-1]))


ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')
plt.show()
```

## Plot

[image]